# Return the date of last activity for an AWS Access Key

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I'm running an audit to gather information about IAM Users and their keys across our AWS accounts. I have the following code to gather the keys:

```
AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient iam = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey);

ListUsersRequest userReq = new ListUsersRequest();
ListUsersResponse userRes = iam.ListUsers(userReq);

foreach (User user in userRes.Users)
{

    ListAccessKeysRequest keyReq = new ListAccessKeysRequest
    {
        UserName = user.UserName
    };
    ListAccessKeysResponse keyRes = iam.ListAccessKeys(keyReq);

    foreach (AccessKeyMetadata key in keyRes.AccessKeyMetadata)
    {
        // Store these values

        // key.AccessKeyId
        // key.UserName
        // key.CreateDate
        // key.Status
    }
}
```

One metric that I would really like to grab is the date a key was last used. That way I can determine which keys can be removed from the accounts while making sure that key isn't currently being used. Is there any API or call I can make to get that information?

Comment: what are the properties of `ListAccessKeysRequest` ? or `AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient`

Comment: `ListAccessKeysRequest` has `UserName`, `Marker`, and `MaxItems`.

Comment: @EFeit Did you find a way to get last access date for the key?

Comment: @savruk Unfortunately I didn't. I opened a case with Amazon, and they confirmed that the SDK doesn't have that functionality. You can gather data from CloudTrail about keys that are being used, but it's not an ideal workaround.